# How to make my old GRUB to be activate on the startup?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have on my machine 3 linux that i installed. 
On installing the second linux (ubuntu 17.04) i define the GRUB as i needed.

I installed the 3rd linux (ubuntu 16.04) and its override my GRUB that i edit and its loading other GRUB

How to make the **first** GRUB to be loaded ?

I try the run the commands below when i running the main linux ( 17.04 ) but nothing work and i still get the bad grub (grub of ubuntu 16.04) that i dont want

```
sudo update-grub
gksu update-grub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load the OS with the wanted grub (17.04) and run the commands:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Be carefull... only if /dev/sda is your disk used to start the machine... else /dev/sdb etc

Comment: Some updates will probably overwrite grub to your system... You have to repeat the above commands every time of grub updates (new kernel or whatever).... From every OS the entries will be the same if you update and then install grub... The  difference is mostly the appearance of the newer version but older versions will give the same entries to youw OSs